Cloud Run times out when accessing PSC endpoint
So I have two Cloud Run Services - the first running in project A and sending traffic to VPC subnet1 and the second running in the project B that is only accepting internal traffic.
In order to send requests from Cloud Run Service A to Cloud Run Service B I have created Private Service Connect with an internal load balancer and NEG that contains Cloud Run Service B.
For the Cloud Run Service A I create the PSC endpoint in the subnet1 of the project A that subscribed to the PSC of the project B.
However, when I send the request from the project A to the subnet1 that contains the endpoint this request times out.
But if I am using VM that is created in the project A and sends the same request it works well and returns response from the PSC Project B.
I was wondering what am I missing here? I want to requests between Cloud Run Service A to Cloud Run Service B to stay within GCP's internal network.

Cloud Run is not connected to your Project A VPC by default, at least it's not clear in your first sentence how you do. You have to set up a direct VPC egress or a serverless VPC connector on the Cloud Run project A to connect it to your VPC.

yes, I have a direct VPC egress setup to the subnet that PSC endpoint is in.

Any firewall rule that block the traffic? With Direct VPC egress you can define a network tag. Grant it to access your PSC, it could be the issue.
